# can't animate second click jquery/css

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

I'm animating the on click using CSS, which works when clicked, but on the second click the animation does not work. The click event is being overridden with jQuery (mainly to allow the dropdown menu to open as a click event instead of hover).

Am I doing something wrong in my CSS? or should I use jQuery to animate the dropdown?

you can view it here: http://elevationspa.wpengine.com

It's the SERVICES tab.

Navigation:

```
<nav id="top-menu-nav">
    <ul id="top-menu" class="nav">
        <li id="menu-item-95" class="mega-menu menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-95"><a href="#">Services</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li id="menu-item-96" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-96"><a href="http://elevationspa.wpengine.com/massage/">Massage</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-97" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-97"><a href="http://elevationspa.wpengine.com/nails/">Nails</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-98" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-98"><a href="http://elevationspa.wpengine.com/hair/">Hair</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-99" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-99"><a href="http://elevationspa.wpengine.com/esthetics/">Esthetics</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-100" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-100"><a href="http://elevationspa.wpengine.com/acupuncture/">Acupuncture</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function($) {

    function setup_collapsible_submenus() {
        var $menu = $('#top-menu'),
            top_level_link = '#top-menu .menu-item-has-children > a';

        $menu.find('a').each(function() {
            $(this).off('click');

            if ( $(this).is(top_level_link) ) {
                $(this).attr('href', '#');
            }

            if ( ! $(this).siblings('.sub-menu').length ) {
                $(this).on('click', function(event) {
                    $(this).parents('.nav').trigger('click');
                });
            } else {
                $(this).on('click', function(event) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    $(this).parent().toggleClass('visible');
                });
            } 
        });
    }

    $(window).load(function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            setup_collapsible_submenus()
        }, 1000);
    });

})(jQuery);
</script>
```

CSS:

```
#main-header #top-menu ul.sub-menu {
        display: none !important;
        visibility: hidden !important;
        transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out;
        animation: gridFadeIn 0.7s ease-in-out both;
      }
#main-header #top-menu .visible  ul.sub-menu {
        display: block !important;
        visibility: visible !important;
        transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out;
        opacity: 1;
        animation: gridFadeIn 0.7s ease-in-out both;
      }
@keyframes grideFadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translatey(-5%);
  }
    100% {
      opacity: 1;
      transform: translatey(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: you can view it here: http://elevationspa.wpengine.com

Comment: still not resolved, any help is appreciated! :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need other visibility properties than `opacity` on the classes:

```
#main-header #top-menu ul.sub-menu {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out;
    animation: gridFadeIn 0.7s ease-in-out both;
  }
#main-header #top-menu .visible  ul.sub-menu {
    transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out;
    opacity: 1;
    animation: gridFadeIn 0.7s ease-in-out both;
  }
@keyframes grideFadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translatey(-5%);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translatey(0);
  }
}
```

Here's the CSS fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/9vmeo97d/5/
Sorry it's a bit messy.

--Addition--

Was a little trickier than I thought at first..
Displaying the submenu on hover comes from the WP theme by jQuery. Assuming the other hover styles are done with CSS (as it seems), add this jQuery to your code to `unbind` the hover event listener from the menu item:

```
$('.menu-item-has-children li').off('mouseenter mouseleave');
```

I'm not sure if I got the selector right, test and comment if not.

Make sure that this script is run after http://elevationspa.wpengine.com/wp-content/themes/Divi/js/custom.js?ver=3.0.35.

Comment: I don't really understand the jQuery solution you have, as my navigation doesn't use divs in that manner, and they also don't use those classes.   The CSS solution also does not work, the visibility property is needed to effectively hide the element until the parent element is clicked.

Comment: I just threw the divs to the fiddle to have some blocks to show/hide. But you can disregard the jquery. The css solution should work.

Comment: the CSS solution does not work properly - yes it allows the animation to work, but it defeats the purpose of allowing the sub-menu to be opened ON CLICK instead of hover.

Comment: Hold on, I'll check. So you don't want it to open on hover, just on click?

Comment: What libraries or addons are you using that makes the menu expand on hover?

Comment: I'm on WordPress using the Divi (child) theme. initially the drop down opens on hover, and as far as i can tell does not use jQuery to do so, only CSS. the jQuery was added to override the option, forcing the user to click the menu to open the drop down instead of hover.

Comment: The JS for the hover is in Divi/js/custom.js: `$et_top_menu.find( 'li' ).hover( function() {...`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137381/discussion-between-trisha-and-sami).